# How can I change the navigation bar title name section in master detail page into the tabbed page menu?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've been struggling with an master detail page.

I have made an navigation page(including tabbed page) in a master detail page. but I don't like this appearance.

As you can see in my description image, I would like to change the title name section into the tabbed menu section.

How can I do for that?

Advise me plz...

```
MainPage = new MasterDetailPage()
              {
                    Master = new ContentPage() { Title = "Menu" },
                    Detail = new NavigationPage(new TabbedPage()
                    {
                        Children = {
                            new ContentPage() { Title = "가" },
                            new ContentPage() { Title = "나" },
                            new ContentPage() { Title = "다" },
                            new ContentPage() { Title = "라" }
                        }
                    })
                };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCr3f.png)

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

In your TabbedPage add Title.

Each page of your tab you must indicate in the constructor the title of your tabbed page.

```
<TabbedPage
    x:Class="Goclubbing.Views.HomeView"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="YOUR TITLE"
    BarBackgroundColor="YOUR_COLOR"
    BarTextColor="YOUR_COLOR"/>
```